# Inverse scaling relationship - iOS pan gesture

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to move a view using a pan gesture. The view's position corresponds to gestures translation, but after a certain point I would like the view to move exponentially slower than the pan gestures translation. I haven't been able to find an equation that will do what I want.

Each time the gesture recognizer is triggered I get its translation value. I use this value to check how far the view has moved since the pan gesture began. Is there a way that I can take difference between the new gesture translation and the last gesture translation and do some sort of quadratic ease on that value to decrease the translation of the view for each cycle?